# Dúvida com function em javaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

eu estou tentando descobrir o que acontece após o click de um botão submit em uma página, para fazer exatamente a mesma coisa em outra. Na página que estou e olhando o código está escrito isso:

```
<button onclick= function (ev) {
ev = ev || window.event;
r = Nwa_SubmitForm("forme1c43235_weblogin","ID_forme1c43235_weblogin_submit");
ev.returnValue = r;
return r;
}>Click me</button>
```

Parece que ele tá chamando a função Nwa_SubmitForm, passando como parametro o id do form e um outro parametro que não sei qual é. 
O "ev" que a função recebe como parametro é o click do botão (o evento)?

Sei que a pergunta está meio vaga. Mas alguém poderia tentar a começar a me ajudar a entender o q este código tá fazendo? Ou por onde posso começar a tentar entender?
Obriagda

Answer (score 0):

A função em questão tem o objetivo de fazer o *handle* do evento `click` (atributo `onclick` no HTML). Tendo isso em vista, o parâmetro em questão (`ev`) é a interface de eventos do JavaScript, que possui uma série de propriedades e métodos relativos ao evento em si.

#### Um simples exemplo:

```js
function handleClick (eventInterface) {
  eventInterface.preventDefault();
  
  alert('A ação padrão deste evento foi prevenida!');
}

const link = document.querySelector('#link');
link.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<a href="/" id="link">Clique em mim.</a>
```

No exemplo acima, criei um link que em tese, ao ser clicado, deveria nos levar à página principal aqui do StackOverflow, mas como usamos o método `preventDefault()`, presente na interface de eventos, a ação padrão foi prevenida.

Esse é somente um dos métodos presentes nessa interface e foi usado apenas como exemplo. Agora que você já sabe que é a interface de eventos, pode dar uma olhada na documentação.

Note que para fins didáticos, nomeei o parâmetro como `eventInterface`, mas a maioria das pessoas utilizam `event`, `ev` ou `e`. Mas como é um parâmetro, você pode nomeá-lo como preferir. :)

#### Referência:

- [Interface de Eventos do JavaScript (`Event`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event);
- [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).